# Swift - Animate Constraints in Custom UIView

Tags: swift, uiview, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to animate constraints in a custom `UIView`. The ending layout is correct, but I cannot get `UIView.animate` to work correctly, and I have seen that everyone is calling `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` from a view controller, so perhaps that is my problem. I am calling `self.layoutIfNeeded()` on the custom view itself. In case the hierarchy matters, I have as follows: ViewController > TableView > Cell > View > AnimationView.

```
class AnimationView: UIView {
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    let ratioMultiplier: CGFloat = 0.28
    var listLeadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var listTrailingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var checkmarkLeadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var checkmarkTrailingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    // MARK: - UI Components
    lazy var listImageView: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImage(named: "list.small")
        let result = UIImageView(image: image)
        return result
    }()
    
    lazy var checkmarkImageView: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImage(named: "checkmark.small")
        let result = UIImageView(image: image)
        return result
    }()
    
    // MARK: - Inits
    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        setupView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        return nil
    }
    
    // MARK: - Methods
    func playAnimation() {
        // 1. change constraints
        listLeadingConstraint.constant += (listImageView.frame.size.width * ratioMultiplier)
        listTrailingConstraint.constant += (listImageView.frame.size.width * ratioMultiplier)
        checkmarkLeadingConstraint.constant += (checkmarkImageView.frame.size.width * ratioMultiplier)
        checkmarkTrailingConstraint.constant += (checkmarkImageView.frame.size.width * ratioMultiplier)
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        
        // 2. animate constraints
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0) {
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
    
    func setupView() {
        // 1. add subviews
        addSubview(listImageView)
        addSubview(checkmarkImageView)
        
        // 2. add constraints       
        ConstraintHelper.anchor(view: checkmarkImageView, options: [.top, .bottom])
        checkmarkLeadingConstraint = checkmarkImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor)
        checkmarkTrailingConstraint = checkmarkImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)
        checkmarkLeadingConstraint.constant -= checkmarkImageView.frame.size.width * ratioMultiplier
        checkmarkTrailingConstraint.constant -= checkmarkImageView.frame.size.width * ratioMultiplier
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([checkmarkLeadingConstraint, checkmarkTrailingConstraint])
        
        ConstraintHelper.anchor(view: listImageView, options: [.top, .bottom])
        listLeadingConstraint = listImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor)
        listTrailingConstraint = listImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([listLeadingConstraint, listTrailingConstraint])
    }
}
```

Additional info: `playAnimation()` is called from `cellForRow` on the table view and I also tried using `self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()` calls to no success. The `ConstraintHelper` calls `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` and the constraints are working correctly, so don't worry about that. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why your initial post is not working is that you called your first `layoutIfNeeded()` after the constraint changes. When your animation block is executed, there's no changes to be animated at all.

It does not matter whether you change the constraints in or out of the animation block.

The common steps are:

1. Call `layoutIfNeeded()` on the rootest view that your constraints may affect. In your case, `self` is ok because all the involving constraints are for the subviews. In some cases, you might change a constraint for the self view, then you need to call `layoutIfNeeded` on its superview.
2. Make your constraint changes: modify constant property, activate/deactivate constraints, etc.
3. Call `layoutIfNeeded()` in a animation block on the same view as you did in the first step.

Please try the following alternative:

```swift
func playAnimation() {
    // Request a layout to clean pending changes for the view if there's any.
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
    
    // Make your constraint changes.
    listLeadingConstraint.constant += (listImageView.frame.size.width * ratioMultiplier)
    listTrailingConstraint.constant += (listImageView.frame.size.width * ratioMultiplier)
    checkmarkLeadingConstraint.constant += (checkmarkImageView.frame.size.width * ratioMultiplier)
    checkmarkTrailingConstraint.constant += (checkmarkImageView.frame.size.width * ratioMultiplier)
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0) {
        // Let your constraint changes update right now.
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the order I had the first layoutIfNeeded() was to confusing me. This answer works and makes much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. Moving the constraint changes to the animation block fixed it, though this is in contrast to most of the posts out there, which say to make constraint changes before the animation block, call layoutIfNeeded() once in preparation, and then a second layoutIfNeeded() in the animation block to force the update and animation. Why this behavior is different in my code, I'm still not sure...

```
func playAnimation() {

    // update constraints & animate
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0) {
        listLeadingConstraint.constant += (listImageView.frame.size.width * ratioMultiplier)
        listTrailingConstraint.constant += (listImageView.frame.size.width * ratioMultiplier)
        checkmarkLeadingConstraint.constant += (checkmarkImageView.frame.size.width * ratioMultiplier)
        checkmarkTrailingConstraint.constant += (checkmarkImageView.frame.size.width * ratioMultiplier)
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```